# Java cast to superclass and call overload method

Tags: java, casting, polymorphism, overriding, overloading

```
abstract class A {

    int met(A a) {
        return 0;
    }

    int met(B b) {
        return 1;
    }

    int met(C c) {
        return 2;
    }
}

class B extends A {

    int met(A a) {
        return 3;
    }

    int met(B b) {
        return 4;
    }

    int met(C c) {
        return 5;
    }
}

class C extends B {
    int f() {
        return ((A)this).met((A)this);
    }
}

public class teste {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        C x = new C();
        System.out.println(x.f());
    }
}
```

The program will return 3 and I was expecting 0. Why does the first cast in the method f do nothing and the second one works? Is it because in the A and B classes the met methods are overloaded and therefore static binding is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just the way polymorphism works. Just consider this example:

```
A a = new C();
a.met(a);
```

This would as expected call the correct method `B#met(...)`. The method-tables for an object don't just change because you change the type of the variable you stored the `Object` in, since the binding between an `Object` and it's methods is stronger than the one between the storage-type and the methods related to it. The second type works, because the type of the input is casted to `A` and thus the method recognizes it as `A` (the type of the input-storage has stronger binding than the `Object` type).